# How do I recover an iPaq that is stuck in "RUU Download Mode"?

Tags: firmware

I recently received a second-hand HP IPaq 114 (in working order).

When I tried to update its firmware using the HP upload utility (SP38992), the device changed to "RUU Download Mode" but the uploader reported error (unfortunately, I didn't record the message, but it was something like "device not found").

Now, the device will only boot into the download mode (i.e. it displays **`RUU Download Mode`** in red, on a white background), and the upload utility reports that it can't find the device.  When I connect it by USB to another machine, I observe that it's emitting `RUUDOWN␀` every 1-2 seconds.

A full reset makes no difference - the device is still stuck in the RUU Download Mode even after a factory reset (i.e. pressing Reset for 3-4 seconds with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>OK</kbd>+<kbd>Record</kbd> held down).

What can I do to get the new firmware onto the device?  I can connect by USB, and I can write to SD card if that might help.  I tried writing the `HPImage.nbf` (from the upload package) to a FAT filesystem on a card, and I tried writing it to the card directly, but neither of those worked.  I also tried simply writing the file to the USB stream, again without success.

How do I rescue this device?

Comment: Did you also press and hold reset for a hard reset/did you try to reset to factory settings? Did you try to use the sync utility?

Comment: I believe that the 'full reset' I described does that - if there's a different factory-reset method, then I'd like to hear it and try it!

Comment: Sync utility doesn't see a device - but that's reasonable, as it probably needs something with working firmware to even communicate with it (if you mean the "mobile device manager" that appears to be a Windows thing, and so wouldn't be expected to understand the firmware transfer, which is a HP thing).  But I'm well out of my depth with this Windows stuff, so I may well be misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how their support site works to actually change the language ... [HP iPAQ 114 Classic Handheld - Zurücksetzen des Geräts auf Werksmodus](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01454887/). It describes that you need to press those 3 buttons and hold down reset for 3-4 seconds. A step which is missing from your description. An alternative seems to be to use the HP Setup Assistant.

Comment: HP Setup Assistant sounds like it might be a useful tool, but I couldn't find how to obtain it anywhere on HP's web site.  Any clues?

Comment: No idea. It should be on the supplied CD but I guess you don't have that one?

Comment: Toby, my understanding is that this uses Windows Mobile (essentially a smartphone without the phone; a PDA).  If that's the case, it wouldn't be on-topic.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes @fixer1234, it's a Windows device (or will be once the firmware is installed).  I thought Windows machines were on-topic here?  If there's a separate Stack Exchange site for Windows machines, I didn't see it - perhaps you could point in the right direction?  It's my first foray into Windows, so I'm a little out of my depth (although reasonably comfortable with flashing firmware onto Linux machines, from Linux workstations).

Comment: Windows and Windows devices are on-topic, but Windows Mobile and Windows Mobile devices are off-topic unless it involves interfacing them with a computer.  There are sites for Android and Apple phone-like devices and I was just investigating whether there's a site for Windows Mobile devices.

Comment: @fixer1234, This certainly does involve interfacing with a desktop computer (and I'm not sure whether the problem is with the device itself or with the updater software on the Windows desktop machine), so that makes it on-topic, I think?

Comment: It looks like there's a Windows Phone Beta site: https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/.  That's the closest I found.

Comment: Yeah, if the issue revolves around interfacing it with a desktop machine, it's on-topic.  Wouldn't hurt to mention that in the question so a trigger-happy close-voter doesn't zing it.  :-)  The issue is centric to the device and the desktop is kind of incidental, so a stickler might balk at it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to connect the updater, and complete the firmware install.

It turns out that the HP upload utility is sensitive to the version of Windows on which it is running.  The first two machines I tried were running Windows version **7**, and on that platform it fails to find the iPaq.

Following advice found elsewhere on the Web, I was able to gain access to a machine with Windows version **XP**.  That system managed to identify the device, and updated it flawlessly.